# ffmpeg gdigrab hidpi mouse capture

Tags: ffmpeg

Have anyone find out how to capture the correct mouse position with ffmpeg on hidpi monitors ? 
There is an issue (https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4232) it says it is fixed, but it isn't in the latest build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found alone the solution and I have opened an pull request. https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/pull/174

Comment: You did see this at Github: *Patches should be submitted to the ffmpeg-devel mailing list using git format-patch or git send-email. Github pull requests should be avoided because they are not part of our review process. Few developers follow pull requests so they will likely be ignored.*

Comment: didn't knew about that, i will check it later. thanks

Answer (score 0):

-On high-DPI (4K) screens there is a mouse pointer offset that can easily be fixed:

```
ffmpeg.exe
ffmpeg-x64.exe
```

->Right-click the executable and select Properties in the context menu,
->Click the Compatibility tab and select Change high DPI settings.
->Click Override high DPI scaling behavior. Scaling performed by: Application.

[image]